# Draw line function

Tags: java

I want to create a drawLine function, however I am not able to use any graphics classes (I can set pixels though). I tried this method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm#Method, but this only works when the line is going from top left to bottom right and not for example going from top right to bottom left. Does anyone have a way that does this? The current code I have:

```
public void drawLine(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    double deltaX = endX - startX;
    double deltaY = endY - startY;
    double error = -1;
    double deltaError = Math.abs(deltaY / deltaX);
    int y = startY;

    for (int x = startX; x < endX - 1; x++) {
        error += deltaError;

        if (error >= 0) {
            y++;
            error--;
        }

        drawPixel(x, y);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

I solved it. The end result is this.

```
public void drawLine(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    if (startX > endX && startY > endY) {
        int startXCopy = startX;
        startX = endX;
        endX = startXCopy;

        int startYCopy = startY;
        startY = endY;
        endY = startYCopy;
    }

    double deltaX = endX - startX;
    double deltaY = endY - startY;
    double error = -1;
    double deltaError = Math.abs(deltaY / deltaX);

    if (deltaX == 0) {
        for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++)
            drawPixel(startX, y);
    }

    if (deltaY == 0) {
        for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++)
            drawPixel(x, startY);
    }

    if (deltaX >= deltaY) {
        int y = startY;
        int yDirection = endY > startY ? 1 : -1;

        for (int x = startX; x < endX - 1; x++) {
            error += deltaError;

            if (error >= 0) {
                y += yDirection;
                error--;
            }

            drawPixel(x, y);
        }
    } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
        int x = startX;
        int xDirection = endX > startX ? 1 : -1;

        for (int y = startY; y < endY - 1; y++) {
            error += deltaError;

            if (error >= 0) {
                x += xDirection;
                error--;
            }

            drawPixel(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing key information: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: I don't really use a GUI Library. I have access to these methods: drawPixel, drawText, drawImage, drawRect and fillRect.

Comment: `"I have access to these methods..."` -- access ***how***?

Comment: you use `x < endX - 1` condition in for loop. For line from top right to bottom left, `startX > endX` so it is never entered.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am not using a GUI to draw things. The methods I showed you were methods I made.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou So when startX >= endX I should revert startX and endX?

Comment: the reason why your lines go from top to bottom is, because the method defined the point of origin (0,0) at top-left

Comment: @stefvanschie revert x's as well as y's.

Comment: @Mas Matts So if the line goes in a different direction I should change the origin. Am I correct?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou That should work for lines that go from bottom right to top left, but it doesn't for lines that go in a different direction, because this method can't draw in other directions than top left to bottom right.

Comment: The usual way to implement these algorithms is first finding which direction is longer. Is the line wider or taller? Then split the execution in two with two parts which specialize in wider lines (iterate x, calculate y) and taller lines. Each of those algorithms then swaps the begin and end coordinates if the for-loop would iterate backwards.

Comment: @stefvanschie yes, that's why before the loop you should check the direction--to give it a chance to enter.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus I got it almost working, but how would I calculate lines that are going perfectly diagonal? There is no longer direction in that case. Should I iterate over the x or the y?

Comment: @stefvanschie doesn't matter. Choose one because both work. You could argue that the algorithm that goes from top to bottom is marginally more efficient because pixel arrays are usually from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. It's working now.

Comment: You can place your answer below as a proper answer rather than an edit to the question

Answer (score 1):

To draw a line is a simple Math problem and can be achieved on different ways.
What you need is the basic linear euqation `y = f(x) = mx + b`
where `m` is your slope, defined as `m=(y2−y1)/(x2−x1)`, `b`is your startY value and the `x` is expressed by `x = x_i - startX` where `x_i` is your current point on your line. Then you can compute all y-values for each `x_i` value on the line between your start point and your end point. The quantity of points depends on a resolution factor.

```
double slope = (double)(endY - startY) / (endX - startX);
//adjustable resolution factor
double resolution = 1;
double x = startX;
while (x <= endX) {
    double y = slope * (x - startX) + startY;
    drawPixel(x, y);
    x += resolution;
}
```